# Gigabyte GA-Z77-D3H single beep

Tags: motherboard

So I've got the build working enough that there is a visable change when i turn the power on: it all goes for 1 second and dies. There is one beep.

I read that is a DRAM problem: Is that correct? What can I do?

Comment: manual does state "One single short beep will be heard if no problem is detected at system startup"... but maybe it does not get a chance to beep more...sense it is only 1 second

Comment: Can you list your power supply? Is it compatible for your 24 pin + 12 pin Mobo power sockets? Also, What RAM are you using? Manufature, speeed and Gigs please.